# Text with underscore in Pentaho Report Desginer

Tags: pentaho

I have lengthy field value which has underscore in it, as a result of which it is displayed dot dot The field value consists of file names containing underscore and comma in between.

I replaced underscore with space and used Wrap-text property, after which I can see all the file names but without underscore. Increasing the width of this field is not an option as it is too long.

How can I see all the file names without being truncated?

Comment: Have you tried setting the x-overflow and y-overflow values. ???

Comment: @Rishu: I tried x-overflow but it arranges the text on a single line which is very long. So it's still truncated as before. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, pentaho reports do not wrap text that does not contain space characters even if the text does not fit in text-field. See PRD's jira:
http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PRD-2736

But maybe it's acceptable for you to replace commas with `", "` string:

```
    =SUBSTITUTE(
        "long_string_number_1,long_string_number_2,long_string_number_3,one_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_long_string,long_string_number_5,long_string_number_6,";
        ",";
        ", "
    )
```

This might decrease a probability to encounter a long string that will not fit your text-box. However you still may encounter following situation (here the second line (very_.._long_string_number_4) was truncated): [image]
**Another option** is to try some mono-space font, and insert line-break after each `i*n` characters where `n` is max number of characters that fit your text-box.

In any case you might want to set dynamic-height property of your text-field to true, so that the field will increase it's height if new lines appear.

**Update:**
As you have requested, I elaborate the second option:
What I meant is to insert into your line line-break characters so that each line would fit your text-field.

1. set the font of the text-box to monospaced – so there will always be the same number of characters fitting your text-field.
2. Count number of characters before your overflow string (the overflow is .. by default). Add number of characters in your overflow string (2 by default).
3. Insert a line-break after each n-th character. For this purpose you can embed into report a function written on python/java or some other language:

   3.1. Proceed to data tab in the upper-right corner of prd. Right click on Functions item, select Add functions option in context
   menu. Unfold Script item and select “Bean-Scripting Framework (BSF)”
   option (you may choose another language if you want).

   3.2. Click on the function you have created, click on the Expression Programming Language value in lower-right section of PRD, then
   select the language you want (select beanshell for my example).

   3.3. Click on the function you have created, click on the Expression item in lower-right section of PRD, then click on [...] button.

   3.4. Write your code to insert line-breaks into your string. Here is an example for you (I am not java developer, so this code might be
   ugly/ineffective/buggy):

   ```java
   import java.lang.StringBuilder;

   // hard-coded string constant as an example data:
   String inputString = "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
   // if you want to get a value from your data source
   // try following line (not tested however):
   // String inputString = dataRow.get("yourColumnName");

   // change maxLineLength constant to the number of characters
   // that fit your text-field
   int maxLineLength = 23;
   int stringLength = inputString.length();

   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   int leftBound = 0;
   int rightBound = maxLineLength;

   while(rightBound < stringLength) {
       String line = inputString.substring(leftBound, rightBound);
       sb.append(line);
       sb.append("\n");
       leftBound = rightBound;
       rightBound += maxLineLength;
   }
   // append remaining characters.
   sb.append(inputString.substring(leftBound, stringLength));

   return sb.toString();
   ```

   3.5. Change the field referenced by your text-field to the name of the function you have created (something like BSFExpression0 by default).

Here is output of my example:

[image]

Remember to replace my inputString and maxLineLength constants with your data. And set dynamic-height of the text-field to true.

Comment: I tried substitute function and there's hardly any difference in the display of file names. Could you please elaborate on "line-break after i*n" solution?

Comment: I created a function (selected Java/BeanShell) named line_break. I added the field defined in my query to inputString variable as: 
**String inputString = dataRow.get("ls_value");** (ls_value is a field in my query)

I then added this function as field value under Attributes tab. But that column is blank now. I have a master report and many sub-reports. I added the function to report header and then in added this function to a particular sub-report using "Edit Sub-reports parameters" by right-clicking Parameter at the bottom under Data tab. I am still getting that column (ls_value) blank now.

Comment: Have you set your "Expression Programming Language" property of your dunction to beanshell? Does this function return any result if you use constant inputString? If no, try function with return statement only (like `return "test";` without any other code).

Comment: Thanks a lot @user4637357. It worked !!! I added the function to each sub-report requiring line break and directed this function to field attribute under Attribute tab.

Comment: Hi @user4637357,

I did set "Expression Programming Language" property to beanshell and that did the trick. Thank You :)